# How to get Geometry of currently focused Window on Linux in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Is there a way to get the Geometry of the currently focused window under Linux? I just need the position (x and y) and size (width and height) of what ever Window is currently having focus or being on top of the desktop.

I want to use this information in my QT application to take a screen shot of this window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, the first step to solve that problem would be to determine the windows that is currently in focus. To do that, you might employ Xlib's [XGetInputFocus()](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGetInputFocus.html) function. After that, use [XGetWindowAttributes()](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetWindowAttributes.html) to get the position and the size of the window (and even some more information about the window).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Striezel, your feedback pointed me in the right direction. After investigating your solution, I run into this post: [Xlib: XGetWindowAttributes always returns 1x1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909713/xlib-xgetwindowattributes-always-returns-1x1)

Tweaking the answer from @Doug a little bit I've got following, which seems to be working as expected:

```
Window getToplevelParent(Display* display, Window window)
{
    Window parentWindow;
    Window rootWindow;
    Window* childrenWindows;
    unsigned int numberOfChildren;

    while (1) {
        if (XQueryTree(display, window, &rootWindow, &parentWindow, &childrenWindows,
                       &numberOfChildren) == 0) {
            qCritical("ImageGrabber::getToplevelParent: XQueryTree Error");
            return 0;
        }
        if (childrenWindows) {
            XFree(childrenWindows);
        }
        if (window == rootWindow || parentWindow == rootWindow) {
            return window;
        } else {
            window = parentWindow;
        }
    }
}

QRect ImageGrabber::getActiveWindowRect()
{

    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window focusWindow, parentOfFocusedWindow;
    XWindowAttributes attrributes;
    int revert;

    XGetInputFocus(display, &focusWindow, &revert);
    parentOfFocusedWindow = getToplevelParent(display, focusWindow);
    if (!parentOfFocusedWindow) {
        qCritical("ImageGrabber::getActiveWindowRect: Unable to get window, returning screen.");
        return getCurrectScreenRect();
    }

    XGetWindowAttributes(display, parentOfFocusedWindow, &attrributes);
    return QRect(attrributes.x, attrributes.y, attrributes.width, attrributes.height);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [libxdo](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool)

```
/**
 * Like xdo_get_focused_window, but return the first ancestor-or-self window *
 * having a property of WM_CLASS. This allows you to get the "real" or
 * top-level-ish window having focus rather than something you may not expect
 * to be the window having focused.
 *
 * @param window_ret Pointer to a window where the currently-focused window
 *   will be stored.
 */
int xdo_get_focused_window_sane(const xdo_t *xdo, Window *window_ret);


/**
 * Get a window's size.
 *
 * @param wid the window to query
 * @param width_ret pointer to unsigned int where the width is stored.
 * @param height_ret pointer to unsigned int where the height is stored.
 */
int xdo_get_window_size(const xdo_t *xdo, Window wid, unsigned int *width_ret,
                        unsigned int *height_ret);
```