# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Desktop: How to get Window Position (X, Y) programmatically of any Desktop application

Tags: java, c++, ubuntu-18.04

I am facing this problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499383/xdotool-getmouselocation-and-getwindowgeometry-y-location-inconsistency

As an alternative I am thinking of a way on how to get the location of any window application in Gnome/Ubuntu 18 Desktop programmatically preferably using either Java/JNA or C++.

Is there a way to get the Window Position (X, Y) coordinate using either Java or C++, in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Desktop, for any Desktop application e.g. Terminal or GEdit?

Specifically, I want to actually get the window location of either Gnome Terminal or GEdit application from a Java/C++ program.

Comment: @kai, sorry to have you confused, but I will be getting any arbitrary application's window (x,y) coordinates that is not created by automator (java/c++) program itself. I want to actually get the window location of either Gnome Terminal or GEdit application from a Java/C++ program.

Comment: can you share the links please?

Comment: this looks  like a nice tutorial on xlib https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ 
and the gtk reference is quite structured and good  https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/

Comment: but like i said not necesarily reilable  and you may find invisible windows(eg for focus reasons) instead of the one you are looking for....

Comment: @kai, the tutorial doesn't contain example codes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188086/discussion-between-artanis-zeratul-and-kai).

Comment: i am there and keep the chat window open ...

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul did you find an answer ? I am interested in similar: getting windows position of Gnome 2.28.2 windows on CentOS 6.8, preferable from Bash or Perl

Comment: @AxelBregnsbo, this is from kai... try this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909713/xlib-xgetwindowattributes-always-returns-1x1 <br /> but it is off by 6 pixels.